# avoiding light through a glass

Tags: materials

How do we avoid light through a glass slab from the world,  materialized with just the default material in blender?
Using an hdr just for lighting the scene is ok, and suppose you want the world to render in a transparent and so under the render panel, under film subpanel we check transparent, but looking the world from the interior- through the glass slab - we can still see the world being rendered. How do we avoid this still retaining the ability of the glass that subtly reflects the interior of the scene?
[image]
(click to enlarge) 
What I mean here is to avoid the image from the world through the glass slab whilst retaining the subtle reflections of the glass slab from the surrounding.

Comment: could you add an image for clarity?

Comment: @FacebFaceb, I added an image.(Should had done it sooner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to rethink what you are really looking for. If you want the refraction part to be actually transparent in the image (have a lower alpha value), you can leave out the glass node entirely. Instead, mix a transparent shader with a glossy shader using a fresnel type of factor. This isn't a physically correct phenomenon anyway, so no need to get all crazy about how to set it up: just something that looks decent is needed.

(This image is plenty high-res enough to see everything clearly even though it doesn't show up correctly here for some reason. Just open it up in a new tab in your browser to see all of the settings or refer to the .blend file.)

[image]

In this blend file, the "transparent" looking areas are actually transparent in the render.

Here is the file that I used for the demo:

[image]

Comment: didn't occur to me in such a manner. thanks!